# single column footnote in multicols environment?

Tags: footnotes, multicol

I use the multicols environment (multicol package).
I have two columns.

If I simply use `\footnote{the footnote text, which is quite long}`
the footnote behaves as if there was just one big column (as in a "normal document").

It seems that there is no regular way to obtain a footnote which only spans one of my two columns.

But I guess there is a workaround like there is e.g. [1] for placing floating objects inside the multicol environment.

I would be grateful for any hint.

[1]
http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/multicol_hint.html

Comment: I understand your problem, but can you please always post a little working example so we don't have to make up one? Thanks.

Comment: These seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480685/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-latex-from-splitting-long-footnotes-across-multiple-col http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=splitfoot

Comment: See also answer of Frank Mittelbach himself: [Footnotes layout in multicols environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68143).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

The workaround you pointed to for single-column floats is a very crude one - the new environments simply don't float, which will almost invariably lead to bad column breaks without manual intervention. Footnotes are a kind of special floats, and an equivalent "workaround" would be to place text formatted akin to footnotes at the bottom of the affected columns by hand (and to determine column breaks by hand).

Quoting from p. 12 of the multicol documentation:

> I'm not sure that I really want pagewide footnotes. But balancing of the last page can only be achieved with this approach or with a multi-path algorithm which is complicated and slow. But it's a challenge to everybody to prove me wrong! Another possibility is to reimplement a small part of the `fire_up` procedure in TeX (the program). I think that this is the best solution if you are interested in complex page makeup, but it has the disadvantage that the resulting program cannot be called TeX thereafter.

So I'm afraid there's no workaround for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you have to use `multicol`?  Normal LaTeX's `twocolumn` mode should work fine with per-column footnotes (I vaguely remember making this work with `bigfoot.sty` at one time, and that would likely have been close to impossible if it did not work without it as well).