# single column footnote in two column layout

Tags: footnotes, two-column

I want to print my affiliation in the bottom of the chapter opening page as a footnote,
I am using a two-column layout.

Is it possible to get a single-column footnote in the two-column layout?

Comment: This question is for single column footnotes with package `multicol`: [Footnotes layout in multicols environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67995). Frank Mittelbach provided a (negative) answer himself.