# Footnotes in one column in twocolumn document

Tags: footnotes

I have a Latex code with twocolumn option in article.cls.

```
\documentclass [11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}

\makeatletter
\newbox\abstract@box
\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\global\setbox\abstract@box=\vbox\bgroup
     \hsize=\textwidth\linewidth=\textwidth
    \small
    \begin{center}%
    {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation}
  {\endquotation\egroup}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@maketitle\expandafter{\@maketitle
  \ifvoid\abstract@box\else\unvbox\abstract@box\if@twocolumn\vskip1.5em\fi\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author[1]{The first author\footnote{Corresponding author:
\\
The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone .}}
\author[2]{The second author}
\affil[1]{University 1}
\affil[2]{University 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\footnote{The first footnote.
The first footnote. The first footnote.
The first footnote.The first footnote.
The first footnote.}
 Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.
The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone.
vamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique 
neque.\footnote{The secont footnote. The author would like to thank someone The author would like to thank someone}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Main text is in two columns and footnotes are in two columns, too. However, I want to have a document wit the footnotes in one column (footnotes span over two columns). 
Note: I do not want to use package \usepackage{multicol}, but only the option that is set in \documentclass [11pt, twocolumn] {article}.

If someone knows the solution and makes an example, I will be very grateful.

Comment: I guess a good answer is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67995/footnotes-layout-in-multicols-environment

Comment: The `ftnright` package make just for the opposite and that could have sense: Long footnotes could have too much characters per line and are  more readable in  narrower columns. Many short notes will left  a huge ragged space at the right.... but I don't see the advantages of doing the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the multicol package instead of twocolumn to solve your issue.
See here:
[How to "force" a footnote to extend over both columns in a twocolumn article?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462347/how-to-force-a-footnote-to-extend-over-both-columns-in-a-twocolumn-article?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Since you asked this three and a half years ago, it probably won't help you, but hopefully someone else finds their answer here.

Comment: I had the same thought. Multicol is the way to go.