# How to "force" a footnote to extend over both columns in a twocolumn article?

Tags: footnotes, two-column

I am trying to create a template based on a twocolumn article. In order to place some banners on the top of the first page, I had to redefine the `\maketitle` command, so now the `\thanks` does not work anymore. Anyway, I think this is not too much of an issue, because I can obtain a similar result with `\footnotetext`.

My problem is that I would like the footnote to extend across both columns (like in a single column environment), while now it simply stays under the left text column. So, I do NOT want the footnote to be split into two columns, but I would like it to extend across the entire textwidth, like this:

> [image]

Since I am trying to create a template that will be used for many different documents, I cannot "cheat" by, for example, replacing the footnote with a `\minipage` or something similar, because I don't know how the text and the footnotes of the "future users" will look like.

This is a simplified example of my current code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %some dummy text
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin, norule]{footmisc} %removes indent and rule from footnote

\newcommand{\customfootnotetext}[2]{{% Group to localize change to footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}% Update footnote counter representation
\footnotetext[0]{#2}}}% Print footnote text

\pagestyle{plain}
\title{This is a title*}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\customfootnotetext{*}{Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot to anyone who will try to help! =)

Comment: Does this help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68143 . The answer was negative six years ago, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: It might be possible to completely rewrite the footnote code to use bottom floats and use the nidanfloat or stfloat packages to allow double column floats on the bottom of the page.

Comment: @KeksDose thank you for the link! Unfortunately I already visited that page but I was still unable to solve my issue =(

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I am still a rather unexpert latex user. So, although I think I understood what you are suggesting to do, I am not quite sure of how to write the relative code. Could you maybe provide me with a small example of how the code could look like?

Comment: Before I get too invested in this question, you might look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way is using `multicol` package instead of `twocolumn` option:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-5]\footnote{\lipsum[6]}
\lipsum[7-8]\footnote{\lipsum[9]}\footnote{\lipsum[10]}
\lipsum[11-16]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```