# How to have a single-column footnote in a two-column layout

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to fit a footnote into a single column in an overall two-column layout (like the two columns shown below)

[image]

How can I get the footnote to appear under only a single column instead?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\begin{document}


\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\section{Section Head}

As conservation\footnote{Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class.} geneticists, we recognize the importance of genetic diversity in maintaining healthy
natural populations, and in facilitating adaptation to new environmental conditions and challenges. However, both population
genetics and the American conservation movement have their roots in the human eugenics movement of a century ago,
which viewed genetic diversity among human populations as grounds for discrimination and prejudice.\footnote{Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.} We acknowledge this
unfortunate part of the history of both population genetics and conservation, and denounce how it has been used to suppress
and disadvantage people.

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020).\footnote{US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.}

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020).\footnote{ Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A.}


Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020).\footnote{Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.}


Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A.\footnote{Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.}

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`ftnright`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ftnright?lang=en) package does exactly this.

ETA: According to this answer [How to "force" a footnote to extend over both columns in a twocolumn article?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462347/how-to-force-a-footnote-to-extend-over-both-columns-in-a-twocolumn-article) the [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=en) package can do this.

Comment: Actually, not quite. But it's still a nice approach: it puts all the footnotes in the right column. Worth checking out, IMO.

Comment: I understood it that way, but thanks for clarifying.