# Revtex4-1: Footnotes in single column format

Tags: revtex

I'm using the `revtex4-1` format. Using footnote splits the footnote text into a two-column format. Although I want my main text to be in a two-column format, I want my footnotes to be in a single column format. Any idea how to do this?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum \footnotetext{This paragraph has been taken from https://www.lipsum.com. This is just sample text.}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is how the footnotes appear currently.

Comment: I guess a good answer is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67995/footnotes-layout-in-multicols-environment