# Making a long footnote span two columns

Tags: footnotes, two-column

I am using an ACM proceedings document class (acm_proc_article-sp) which uses a standard 2-column layout.  I have a very long, unbreakable footnote that needs to span both columns.  Is this possible?

Currently it appears on the left or right, depending on where in the body the `\footnote` command is used.  If it appears on the left column, it spans the full page and if another footnote appears on the right column, they are drawn on top of each other.  Or if it appears on the right column, then half of it goes off the page.

Comment: Related, but in my eyes no duplicate: [single column footnote in multicols environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/single-column-footnote-in-multicols-environment). The same here: [Footnotes layout in multicols environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67995/footnotes-layout-in-multicols-environment).

Comment: Yes my case is somewhat the opposite of your first link. This ACM class gives footnotes that are single column by default and I need one that spans both columns.

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Comment: No, I still don't have an answer for this problem.  My footnote was a URL, so I just made a short URL out of it to avoid the problem.

Comment: The real issue is the missing line-breaking in your URL. There are a bunch of questions and answers dealing with this.